# Do references and pointers by default always represent the 0 index? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, reference

The title pretty much sums up the question. But i'll add a few extra details. Say your trying to pass an argument into a function, for this sake the argument is either a vector or array. When you do:

```
void printFun(vector<int>& aVec)
{
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> someVec;
    printFun (someVec);
}
```

is the reference in aVec taking it at index zero (or the first index); so then you'll have to aVec[index] with index incrementing to go through, print or modify, every value.

If it seems like any additional advice that you think may help needs to be said to greater understand this that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> is the reference in aVec taking it at index zero

That question doesn't make much sense. The vector does not have any index state. You access elements by passing an index of your choosing. A reference is just an alias for an object. It is decoupled from indexing.

**Edit**: Following comments, to clarify: The reference is an alias for the whole vector, not for any element of the vector at any particular index. References have nothing to do with indexing.

Comment: if someVec making an alias from the first element then, and then with contiguous memory address you can use an aVec[index] to stream through the elements?

Comment: @Jcodin It is not an alias for the first element. It is an alias for the vector. You use it just like you use any vector in any other context.

Comment: then why make a reference for it? if you didn't would you have to manually type all the values into the parameters?

Comment: @Jcodin In this case, a reference allows to to refer to an object that has been created outside of the function. You may want to do this so you can modify the object, or to avoid making a potentially expensive copy of it, or both.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave the reference "aVec" is not a reference to an index in the vector, it is a reference to the vector itself.

Assuming the vector has any elements, you can get the object at index 0 like this

```
void printFun(vector<int>& aVec)
{
    //access index 0
    aVec[0] = 0;

    //To iterate the vector you can do this
    for( int i = 0; i < aVec.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << aVec[i];
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you´re passing an array to a function (ie. a pointer),
it points always exactly to the first element.
`p[0]` is always the same as `*p`

With a vector pointer (which is a class with one of maybe multiple members being an array)
this is not guaranteed. Can be, but have not to.
And a vector reference is another thing. It´s not the same as a pointer.

Comment: Probably down to the weird statement about the vector pointer.